# How to make a shared resource thread-safe when using dependency injection?

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, dependency-injection, thread-safety, locking

My current application is using single instance of an object as a global variable for many of the main components, which I understand is considered inferior to using dependency injection.

I wish to make my applications open source in the future, but first I want to refactor the code to use the most recommended techniques for team collaboration so that other developers will be able to change my source code more easily.

Example of a shared resource: In the CFML language, you have the Server scope, which is shared memory that is available to any request for the entire server instance.

Here is my new design concept for managing changes to the Server scope:

1. Create a single instance of component named ServerMemoryManager which provides an interface for writing and reading to the server scope.
2. Any other code that needs to access the server scope will be injected with a reference to the single instance of the ServerMemoryManager via an init() function or a setServerMemoryManager() function.
3. Whenever a component reads/writes data to the ServerMemoryManager object, it will be able to internally lock the server scope so that no 2 threads can simultaneous write to the same piece of memory in the server scope.

Is this the best way to manage a shared resource (shared memory, filesystem, etc) that requires locking in order to be thread-safe?

Please describe any additional methods that can be used to manage a shared resource that requires locking during certain read/write operations which are considered best practices.

**Edit:** Based on the accepted answer, instead of locking scope="server", I will use named locks and manage the shared resources with more fine-grained locking.  This may allow using multiple objects to manage the shared resources assuming they are all managing different keys in shared memory or files in the filesystem.  For example, one application could have its own unique key or directory assigned to it so that it wouldn't conflict with another application trying to change a shared resource.

**Edit2:** I found I could use a single component named scope.cfc for each scope if I pass the scope into the init function when I create the object.  I am now using fine-grained named locks.  Let me know if it can be improved. The actual revised code now looks like this (I excluded the code for read, delete, clear).  It also doesn't seem that it is required to have a single instance of the scope.cfc component anymore.

```
            <cfcomponent>
                <cfscript>
                variables.scope=false;
                variables.scopeName=false;
                </cfscript>
                <cffunction name="init" access="public" output="no" returntype="scope">
                    <cfargument name="scope" type="struct" required="yes">
                    <cfargument name="scopeName" type="string" required="yes">
                    <cfscript>
                    variables.scope=arguments.scope;
                    variables.scopeName=arguments.scopeName;
                    return this;
                    </cfscript>
                </cffunction>
                <cffunction name="write" access="public" output="no" returntype="boolean">
                    <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="yes">
                    <cfargument name="value" type="any" requires="yes">
                    <cfargument name="timeout" type="numeric" required="no" default="10">
                    <cftry>
                        <cflock type="exclusive" name="zcore-#variables.scopeName#-scope-#arguments.key#" timeout="#arguments.timeout#" throwontimeout="yes">
                            <cfscript>
                            variables.scope[arguments.key]=arguments.value;
                            </cfscript>
                        </cflock>
                        <cfcatch type="lock"><cfreturn false></cfcatch>
                    </cftry>
                    <cfreturn true>
                </cffunction>
            </cfcomponent>
```

** Edit3:** I tested the performance of reading from server scope through a component method like this and found it to be 20 times slower then reading the server scope directly when using a read only lock and 4 times slower without a lock.  The overhead of an extra function call hundreds or thousands of times per request will be too slow.  Tests done on Railo 3.3.x.

I prefer to build a large object in a non-public request and then set a single shared memory scope key then try to write an incomplete object to the scopes.  Example:

```
<cfscript>
ts=structnew();
ts.largeObject=buildLargeObject();
server.cachedObject=ts;
</cfscript>
```

This lets you avoid locking across the entire application when you only write complete objects to shared memory since updating a single struct key is thread-safe.  However, when you build the large object on startup, you need to be sure it is locked until that object is fully created.

I'm going to make the scope variable become directly readable by using the this scope instead of variables scope in the init function to avoid slowing down the application.

Comment: Can you clarify step 3. Will the locking be handled internally by the ServerMemoryManager, or will users of this component need to call methods on the component to lock before data read/write? I hope its the  case that the locks are managed internally.

Comment: @Brady The locks will be managed internally in ServerMemoryManager component.  I would ideally have everything related to a shared resource encapsulated with the simplest public interface possible.

Comment: That sounds like a good design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CFLOCK only prevents code from executing if every occurrence is locked the same way.

For example:

**page1.cfm**

```
<cflock type="exclusive" scope="server" timeout="10" >
   <cfset application.xyz = 'abc'>
</cflock>
```

**page2.cfm**

```
<cfset application.xyz = '123'>
```

Page2.cfm is going to negate any locks you have on page1.cfm if page2 runs the same time page1 does.  That said, it's good that you are locking inside your cfc so that each object doesn't have to be locked.

However, locking every occurrence isn't enough. The following won't do much good either.

**page1.cfm**

```
<cflock type="exclusive" scope="server" timeout="10" >
   <cfset application.xyz = 'abc'>
</cflock>
```

**page2.cfm**

```
<cflock type="exclusive" scope="server" timeout="10" >
   <cfset application.xyz = '123'>
</cflock>
```

This will halt the processing for every request of page1 and page2 but will not protect application.xyz on page1 from changes made to application.xyz on page2. To do this you need to [give your locks a "name"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5d.html).

> Locks name. Mutually exclusive with the scope attribute. Only one
>   request can execute the code within a cflocktag with a given name at a
>   time. Cannot be an empty string.
>
> Permits synchronizing access to resources from different parts of an
>   application. Lock names are global to a ColdFusion server. They are
>   shared among applications and user sessions, but not clustered
>   servers.

Because you are creating multiple instances of your object, I believe `serverMemoryManagerObject` could interfere with `serverMemoryManagerObject2` unless you name your lock.

Here is some more information about locking dos and don'ts

- [Locking code with cflock](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7cc4.html)
- [CFLock And Negative Outcomes Think It Through](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1123-CFLock-And-Negative-Outcomes-Think-It-Through.htm)
- [CFMythbusters - Countering Some Conventional Wisdom](http://www.carehart.org/presentations/CFMythbusters.pdf)

Comment: you mixed server and application scope which breaks the locking - was that a mistake? There are multiple objects that depend on 1 instance of serverMemoryManagerObject above.  cflock scope="server" will safely lock server scope and cflock scope="application" will safely lock application scope so I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me other then I should try to lock in a more fine grained way to avoid blocking other requests too much - I will do that.  I was also going to have a separate component for each shared resource.  I.e for application, session, filesys, etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mixing scopes breaks the locking. From the docs: "The cflock tag prevents simultaneous access to sections of code, not to variables." I used setting an application scope variable as an example but I could have just as easily said "I don't want anyone on my server accessing {this shared cfc/custom tag that reads/writes files to a shared folder} at the same time"

Comment: I was interpreting cflock scope attribute to mean it locked the nested server scope structure, but it doesn't.  You are right and I've managed to not understand cflock correctly for many years, yet my app was working for the most part since I locked the parts that needed to be locked.   I will have to re-consider how I use cflock in the future.  I think I'll have separate components that deal with separate keys within the server scope and use named locks instead of cflock scope="server".   I didn't realize I was thinking about this wrong.  I'll mark you as the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Easily confused. Perhaps if the attribute was called something else like environment or extent or confines... Read the four links I posted, there is a lot of good stuff there.